# Google Visualization: Column Chart, simple question but can't find the answer

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/columnchart.html

I'm using the above api to create an interactive column chart.  I would like a numeric text shown above each bar which would display the value for that data point.

Does anyone know how to enable this feature.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't sound like this is available right now. I was looking for this too.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/browse_thread/thread/d8fc6ba98bf66419/4e3df7767d0d8417?lnk=raot&pli=1