# How to show values on the top of columns Google Chart API

Tags: charts

I would like to show values on the top of my columns chart
just like in this image:

[image: expected chart]

But I want to show them using the new Google Chart API.
Here is [the site](http://www.metannonce.com/teste.html)  and its [source code](http://pastebin.com/Ev3rSGiM).

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
data.addColumn('number','a');
data.addColumn('number','v');
data.addColumn('number','c');
data.addColumn('number','e');
data.addRows(5);
data.setCell(0, 0, 'dfa');
data.setCell(1, 0, 'Sdfa');
data.setCell(2, 0, 'Mdz');
data.setCell(3, 0, 'sd');
data.setCell(4, 0, 'Rsdr');
data.setCell(0, 1,  114);
data.setCell(1, 1,  723);
data.setCell(2, 1, 238);
data.setCell(3, 1,  509);
data.setCell(0, 2,  636);
data.setCell(1, 2,  410);
data.setCell(2, 2,  395);
data.setCell(3, 2,  668);
data.setCell(0, 3,  508);
data.setCell(1, 3, 709);
data.setCell(2, 3,  686);
data.setCell(3, 3, 533);
data.setCell(0, 4, 643);
data.setCell(1, 4, 737);
data.setCell(2, 4,  964);
data.setCell(3, 4,  945);
var chart =   new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).
draw(data,
{title:"Parc localisé par région et par offre", 
width:500, height:300,
series: {0:{color: '#CF0980', visibleInLegend: true}, 1:{color: '#999999', visibleInLegend: true}, 2:{color: '#990099', visibleInLegend: true}, 3:{color: '#FF99CC', visibleInLegend: true}},isStacked:"true"});}
</script>  
</head>
<body><div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can see my code on the link i wrote ( here is my code )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Visualization: Column Chart, simple question but can't find the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409060/google-visualization-column-chart-simple-question-but-cant-find-the-answer)

Comment: There is a workaround described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047650/how-to-label-google-column-chart-bars

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
annotations: {
    alwaysOutside: true
}
```

to the config object

Comment: Thanks, just used this today and it worked for what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

For column chart it is not possible.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-visualization-api/2PxrqYv2ZBk

But with this deprecated image chart it is:
https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard
You can used shape marker with number type, but it is deprecated so no use.

Comment: It's possible to do it with the column chart (I've done it), but I had to write my own method for setting the axis values to ensure there is enough space for annotations at the top.