# put labels on top of inside bar in google interactive bar chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have created a bar chart using google [Column Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart), now

1. I have only integer values in my datatable but google divide acis with float values, is there a way to force chart mark only integers?
2. is there any way to show value labels on top or inside bar chart? I found some way for image chart, but I whould like to keep chart interactive

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Visualization: Column Chart, simple question but can't find the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409060/google-visualization-column-chart-simple-question-but-cant-find-the-answer)

Comment: Arsen, to make your post clearer your should not asked 2 unrelated questions in 1 post, see this post : http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106530/179059.You should ask the first question in its own post if you want it to have enough attention. Btw in your case I think both are duplicates. Let me know if you need a different answer for your first question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem you can use `gridlines` property, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9211416/1140748) to see how you can use it.

For the second question I don't really understand. When you go on a bar with your mouse, the popup with values isn't  already displayed on the top of the bar?

Comment: Thanks for fast reponse @alain.janinm, sure tooltip shows label, but I whould like to show static labels on top of every bar

Comment: @alan.janimn I want something like this http://www.fintrac-canafe.gc.ca/publications/FOR/2008-05-05/re-ai-fig1-eng.gif

Comment: @ArsenMkrt Ok so your question is a dup : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5409060/1140748 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9098322/1140748. And it's still not have any answer for ColumnChart, here is an exemple with barchart : http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#image_bar_chart. The new feature that maybe will help in the future is annotations : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#whatareroles. Unfortunately this feature is not usable with columnchart... So now you can't do that without some wired hack. The best solution : wait some months ;)

Comment: For a custom function to show only integers as grid axis separators, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251474/how-do-i-read-and-modify-axes-on-an-already-drawn-google-chart/14270431#14270431

Answer (score 12):

There is no direct solution to this as yet because annotations are not supported in column chart. But let me share a work around for this: You can create a combo chart with two series having same data (as that of your column chart) along with the annotation column. Set the type of the first series to *bars* and that of the other series to *line*. Finally, specify *visibleInLegend*, *lineWidth*, and *pointSize* properties of the second series to *false* and *0s* respectively.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn({ type: 'string', label: 'Labels' });
data.addColumn({ type: 'number', label: 'Bar Series' });
data.addColumn({ type: 'number', label: 'Line Series' });
data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'annotation' });

data.addRows([['Label1', 10, 10, '10'],
             ['Label1', 20, 20, '20'],
             ['Label1', 40, 40, '40'],
             ['Label1', 5, 5, '5'],
             ['Label1', 30, 30, '30'],
             ]);

var barchart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('bar_element'));
var options = {series: [{ type: 'bars' },
                        { type: 'line', lineWidth: 0, visibleInLegend:false, pointSize: 0}]};

barchart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with more than one data point per series? For example `[['Label1', 10, 40, 10, '10', 40, '40'], ['Label2', 20, 5, 20, '20', 5, '5']]` with bar, bar, line, annotation, line, and annotation columns would show the annotations in the middle of the two bars, because there's no way to "stagger" the two line series to align with the two bar?