# Display value labels on multi-series google column charts

Tags: google-visualization

Is anyone know wether there is a way to display the values of a **multi-series** google column chart over each columns ?

Muhammad Tayyab Shei succeded in making it, but for a **single-serie** : see [put labels on top of inside bar in google interactive bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871729/put-labels-on-top-of-inside-bar-in-google-interactive-bar-chart)

Comment: How far did you get yourself? Any point where you got stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Since the annotation role is not supported for column charts yet, it cannot be done with a multi-column chart (the single-series version works by using a combo-chart which allows annotations for the line chart portion).

The easiest way to implement this would be to create a javascript function to either display the tooltips full time, or to draw custom tooltips and turn them on (using [HTML-enabled Tooltips](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#enabling_html_tooltip), for instance).

Comment: So I've searched and tried, but I'm not good enough : I didn't find a way to make it !
If anyone can hepl...